# How to get the parent item in Firebase when onChildAdded event is triggered?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Considering the following code example:

```
// Get a reference to our posts
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/posts");
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
// Retrieve new posts as they are added to the database
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
    BlogPost newPost = snapshot.getValue(BlogPost.class);
    System.out.println("Author: " + newPost.getAuthor());
    System.out.println("Title: " + newPost.getTitle());
}
//... ChildEventListener also defines onChildChanged, onChildRemoved,
//    onChildMoved and onCanceled, covered in later sections.
});
```

Is it possible to get DataSnapshot parent item in Firebase when onChildAdded is triggered?

Answer (score 2):

Since you've only retrieved the child, the `DataSnapshot` does not contain the data for the parent item. But it is easily accessible at `ref`.

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
  ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot parent) {
      System.out.println("Got parent");
    }
    ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is quite old, but here's what worked for me

```
@Override
public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
       DatabaseReference parent = dataSnapshot.getRef().getParent();
       if( parent != null){
             String parentNode = parent.getKey();
       }
 }
```

So basically calling .getRef().getParent().getKey() on a Datasnapshot should do the work.